# Good way to open a text/xml file via JQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

Is there a good way to open a text/xml content type via JQuery or Javascript?

I want the header to be like so:

```
"content-disposition: attachment; filename=thexml.xml";
```

Comment: Open in browser ? Or, download from browser ?

Comment: Download from a browser...is the only way to do a callback to the server?

Comment: Tried the `download` or `downloadURL` attribute on `html` element ? i.e.g., `download=thexml.xml` ?